# First-order model checking on general graphs is intractable

Tags: graphs, model-checking, parameterized-complexity

I read that the first-order model checking problem is intractable on general graphs.

How is this shown? Would be happy about some reference!

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [these slides](https://algo2017.ac.tuwien.ac.at/wp-content/uploads/slides_vienna.pdf), second slide.

Comment: Could you und explain pls

Comment: It's explained in the slides.

Comment: I am sorry I don't see it. Maybe I am blind or just unable to read between the lines. Would be happy if you could help.

Comment: The second slide gives two well-known NP-complete problems which can be expressed as first-order model checking problems on graphs.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I thought but I was unsure. 
Looking at Dominating set of size at most k:
Any FO formula can only represent the problem for a fixed k for which the problem is polynomial. I think that's why I couldn't quite get it together in my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent classical NP-complete problems as model checking of first-order formulas in the language of graphs, for example subgraph isomorphism, dominating set, clique, vertex cover, and so on.

Comment: I think I have one more question, namely how do we know that none of these problems is tractable?
For example we know that k-colouring can not be fpt because we would get a polynomial algorithm for 3-colouring if k-colouring would be tractable at all.
But if the problems are not NP-complete or NP-hard for some fixed k then NP complete/hard does not imply intractable.
Something does not add up in my head, I hope I do not annoy you.

Comment: You can reduce, in polynomial time, an instance of, say, clique to an instance of first-order model checking on graphs.

Comment: NP-hard is considered intractable. Your problem is certainly decidable.

Comment: sorry I deleted my comment right away because I realized it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi again, I think I mixed up some things here. 
I read that FO model checking is intractable and that it is also believed to be not fixed parameter tractable and somehow I thought these two things mean the same thing.
I realized that intractable only means that we believe it can not be solved in polynomial time. So an easy reduction from some NP-complete problem shows that FO model checking on graphs is intractable.
My other question is why FO model checking is believed to be not fixed parameter tractable on general graphs? Is this in any way related to classical Complexity theory?

Comment: This sounds like an altogether different question.